# AWS RDS Postgres performance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, python, django

We are using rds(postgres) with instance type as db.m4.2xlarge.

Usually most of the time number of connections are 8-10. But on some occasion as the number of connections increases to 100-200. DB becomes non-responsive. DB non-responsiveness we have seen many time in cases of sudden spike in number or read connections(so even in cases where connections have increases from 10 to 100).

Queries which are being executed at max takes 2sec to execute.

My application server is running on django/python stack(with Gunicorn). Latency of these servers go high when DB server response time increases.

Any changes in configuration of postgres rds we should do to improve performance(currently most of the settings are default) ?

Comment: 2 seconds is a really slow query for a web page load.

Comment: That is actually the max query time.. there are lot of queries which are getting executed in ms. But this should not cause rds slowdown(cpu utilization is going to 100%) in that rds instance type

Comment: Not much we can help - way too little data. We need at least: what queries are slow (check `select now()-query_start, query from pg_stat_activity where state<>'idle' order by 1`), how large RDS disk size (small sizes are extremely slow), which non-default db parameters you use. You may also use pg_stat_statements extension to see worst queries from some time span etc.

Comment: We analyzed our system more.. Issue is not with queries and nither with number of concurrent requests.. throughput was very high at that given point of time.. So we tweaked some postgres configurations and monitoring how it performs now.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue. The postgresql is setup on AWS RDS and it was having 100% cpu utilisation even after increasing the instance. I debugged with the method shown [here](https://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2016/10/debug-postgresql-performance-issues.html) and one of the method worked for me.

I checked for the query running for the longest time and came to know that certain queries was stuck and was running since more than 3-4 hours. To check since how much time the query is running, run the following command:

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity
                               WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

If this is more than an hour, than this is the issue. Kill the long running connection and limit the max age of the connection from application side.

Comment: In our case we were not even able to login to postgres shell due to load for running commands.. On more analysis we found n/w traffic load of aws was failing on high load times.. We replicated db for solution of same

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you have one query which is particularly slow. When this runs the connections pile up behind it. I'd start by identifying the problematic query and then figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Dave, do you have any practical suggestions on how to do that? Is there some kind of query monitor, a slow query log you can turn on, etc? If so I suggest you update your post to include it.